# WPF TextBox Text does not update with word suggestions with Windows 10 v1803

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, keyboard, windows-10

It appears the recent Windows 10 1803 update has broken word suggestions for WPF Textboxes and I am looking for workarounds. We have tried .NET 4.5.2 and .NET 4.6.2.

**Scenario**: simple WPF app, one TextBox. Either with hardware suggestions or touch keyboard suggestions, enter a character and then select a suggested word (ex. p, then 'poke'). If watching the visual tree with a tool like Snoop, the TextBox text property will not change. It is not until you commit another letter that the Textbox applies the text update - encompassing all the previous suggestions you entered.

In fact, I can't seem to even find the selected word in the visual tree at all! It shows up on the screen, but not in a public field.

The issue here is we're relying on some preview events to filter out some inputs (paste or key input), and when the preview event happens for the following character after a suggestion, the original text returns the text from the box BEFORE the suggestion ('p' in this case), but caret thinks it's down the line. Therefore, we get an out of bounds exception.

Other than asking all our customers to disable word suggestions in Windows, any ideas? I see no WPF events firing and cannot find the data in the visual tree.

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: Hi, we discovered the same issue, but for us, it's mostly the Text property binding going out of the window that is very problematic.
Have you found a workaround for this? I also saw your post on MSDN forum, but it didn't get much attention from MS :(

Comment: I've created a bug report as I didn't find any matching it. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/320417/wpf-textbox-texts-binding-failing-due-to-word-pred.html

Comment: Sadly, nothing yet.